# Custom errors pages on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I add to my app_controller.rb this code:

```
  protected

  def render_optional_error_file(status_code)
    status = interpret_status(status_code)
    render :template => "/errors/#{status[0,3]}.html.erb", :status => status, :layout => 'application.html.erb'
  end

  def local_request?
    false
  end
```

Add to my environment.rb:

```
  config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

And I delete errors pages from public.

How can I test my new errors pages?
If I go to /404 I see routing error.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but try running this command to start your server:

> rails server -e production